# Jetpack Compose viewModel never cleared

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

I need your help.

I'm porting a large application from iOS (**iPad**) to Android (**Tablet only**), using **Jetpack Compose**.

This is the context.
I've got a list of Pins (objets on a map). A pin is a very complex element with many parameters (states, photos, history, and about 20 parameters more)
When I select a pin in the list, I want to display a dialog with all the details of the pin.
This is my code.

```
fun PinList(viewModel: PinListViewModel) {
    …
    LazyColumn(..) {
        items(viewModel.pins, key = {it.identifier}) { pin ->
            PinCell(pin, …)
        }
    }
    …
}

private fun PinCell(pin: Pin, …) {
    var showDetails by remember { mutableStateOf(false)) }
    …
    Row(modifier = Modifier.clickable { showDetails = true }, …) {
        …
    }
    …
    if (showDetails) {
        PinDetailsDialog(pin, onDismissRequest = { showDetails = false }
    }
}
```

The details view is so complex that I need a viewModel to manage it (the pin parameters can be edited)

```
fun PinDetailsDialog(pin: Pin, onDismissRequest: () -> Unit) {
    val viewModel: PinDetailsViewModel = viewModel()
    viewModel.pin = pin     // Needed !!

    Dialog(onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest, …) {
    …
    }

    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        Log.d(TAG, "PinDetailsDialog onAppear")
        onDispose {
            Log.d(TAG, "PinDetailsDialog onDispose")
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the viewModel

```
class PinDetailsViewModel: ViewModel() {
    …

    init {
        Log.d(TAG, "PinDetailsViewModel init")
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        Log.d(TAG, "PinDetailsViewModel onCleared")
    }
    …
}
```

OK. Now the problem :-)

I run the app, select a pin in the list and get logs

```
PinDetailsViewModel init
PinDetailsDialog onAppear
```

I close the dialog

```
PinDetailsDialog onDispose
```

As you can see, the dialog is disposed but the viewModel is never cleared. And I know why. PinDetailsDialog is maintains in the composition tree cache of PinCell and never released.
This is a problem because this viewModel is huge and never be released all along the app run. And I will have others same cases later.

I would like the PinDetailsViewModel to be released when I close the dialog.

Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You can try clearing `ViewModel` manually in Disposable Effect i.e.,

```
val context = LocalContext.current as Activity
DisposableEffect(key1 = "Dialog Reference/Key", effect = {
  onDispose {
    context.viewModelStore.clear()
  }
})
```

Comment: I don't want clear all viewModels but only the one created for the dialog view

Comment: Since Navigation Component v2.1.0-alpha02, ViewModels could now be scoped to a flow. The downside to this is that you have to implement Navigation Component to your project and also you have no granualar control to the scope of your ViewModel. You can try this approach:  
 https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-with-saved-state-jetpack-navigation-data-binding-and-coroutines-df476b78144e